# How to add a control point (Bézier curve) between two Offsets?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to animate a picture sliding on the screen. So far I'm using a `Tween<Offset>` to lerp between two offsets: `Tween(begin: startOffset, end: destOffset)`. This animates the picture sliding in a straight line.

Is there an easy way to add a control point to form a Bézier curve? I see there's `quadraticBezierTo` in `Path` class, but I don't know how to transform between an `Offset` (or a `Point`) class to a `Path` class. Another way is to create my own `Tween` that calculates a Bézier curve instead of just doing `lerp`, but I thought I'd ask before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not difficult to write a BezierTween that calculates a Bezier curve with a control point:

```
class BezierTween extends Tween<Offset> {
  final Offset begin;
  final Offset end;
  final Offset control;

  BezierTween({this.begin, this.end, this.control})
      : super(begin: begin, end: end);

  @override
  Offset lerp(double t) {
    assert(begin != null);
    assert(end != null);
    assert(control != null);
    final t1 = 1 - t;
    return begin * t1 * t1 + control * 2 * t1 * t + end * t * t;
  }
}
```

To use it, change:

`Tween(begin: startOffset, end: destOffset` from the question, to:

`BezierTween(begin: startOffset, end: destOffset, control: controlOffset)`

However I'm still wondering if this kind of use case is already built into the awesome Flutter framework.

Comment: A null-safe version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69625887/1032613