# how to control bezier animation?

Tags: flutter, animation, tween, explicit

i need similar animation like [How to animate widget along a curved bezier path from start point to end point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625816/how-to-animate-widget-along-a-curved-bezier-path-from-start-point-to-end-point) but with the possibility to be able to stop/resume(control) the animation. How can i do this? If i use AnimationController, i need to calc every point by myself. So i looking for somthing like that

```
 controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      vsync: this,
    );

   

    bezierTweenController = BezierTween(
      begin: Offset.zero,
      end: Offset.zero,
      control: Offset.zero,
    ).animate(controller);
```