# Flutter realtime video overlay

Tags: flutter, video, artificial-intelligence, video-processing

I want to create a video player in Flutter that will highlight cars in the video something like this[image] For every frame of the video I have info where the cars are located inside the frame but I'm not sure how can I draw boxes around each car and have it synced with every frame?

I plan to use [media_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit) package for video playback because it supports desktop and that is a requirement. If you know any other package that could help me feel free to share that!

Any help is welcomed! Thank you!

Comment: I'm also looking for a video player package that can notify me every time a new frame is being shown. Have you found something like this?

Comment: I made it work with media_kit. To calculate the current frame index I used VideoController.player.stream.position

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I believe you want to create a Computer Vision application, which is not as simple as drawing rectangles on top of a video source. You'll need to use some algorithm to analyze each frame and identify your target objects.

On the other hand, due to the lack of the exact description, and since you just say you want to draw rectangles over a video, it's not as hard as it seems.

All you need is to use a `Stack` widget and place the video widget as
the first element, and use the `Positioned` element to draw one or more `Container`(s) or `SizedBox`(es) with a default red border, where their position and size are based on some animation controller.

The animation can be directly linked with the video play timer, and your box animation can vary depending on the amount of data you have for the animation.

Here's some examples that might help you up:

[Video regarding Positioned Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC3s2YdtWt8) 
[StackOverflow article regarding Path Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625816/how-to-animate-widget-along-a-curved-bezier-path-from-start-point-to-end-point/69625887#69625887)

More advanced stuff related to [Computer Vision and detecting Vehicles](https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-vehicles-using-machine-learning-and-computer-vision-e319ee149e10), if you want to go down this rabbit hole.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My main issue is synchronizing the boxes with video frames. How can I get the info that there is a new video frame shown so that I can update my car boxes?

Comment: If the animation sync is your only issue, you can use the video's current time and sync it with your animation frames/list objects, which should contain the information when the object appears on the video, current size, position, etc. This can be managed in different ways. From storing frame-by-frame info, which takes a lot of info, to having movement paths, which are less accurate, but easier to manage.