# List item animation between columns

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I basically have a layout with two columns.

When something happens on an item on the left column, I want to animate it to the bottom of the column on the right (where the read footer is)

[image]

The first problem is that I'm new to flutter animations and to be honest I don't even know where to start. PositionedTransition seems to be the best fit, but not quite sure how it would overlay into a diffent list.

The second problem is that the initial and final locations will have to be dynamic, as both the affected list item (initial) and the red footer (final) can be anywhere in the visible part of the lists.

Do you guys have any tips, ideas, examples that I can take a look?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your task can be broken down into 2 main concepts, and I've answered similar questions on both concepts before.

1. Animate an item from a list to another list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69470439/1032613
2. Apply a Bézier curve to the animation path:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/61129258/1032613

Comment: Woah, I guess with a bit of modification this has the potential to work. Sadly my focus has changed a little bit, but this could definitely work.

Comment: @RobertEstivill No worries, I landed here when trying to search for my own answer in the other post. Your title is more descriptive so maybe more people would land here in the future too. I'll just leave this "answer" up to redirect future readers then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do but maybe this is what you want.

Search the Draggable -[this](https://blog.logrocket.com/drag-and-drop-ui-elements-in-flutter-with-draggable-and-dragtarget/#:%7E:text=Draggable%20is%20a%20Flutter%20widget,pointer%2C%20the%20feedback%20widget%20disappears.)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Sadly that's not what I'm looking for. I am looking to animate the item from the left column and make it fly over the column on the right.

Comment: Yes I got it I guess there isn't much of a way to do this but you can try the Hero widget.